# Run asm in Visual Studio code

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code, x86, att

Is there some sort of plugin in Visual Studio code (mac) that can run basic assembly, for example the following:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

As it is, currently I am ssh'ing into a linux server in order to run this assembly but I was hoping it would be possible to build/link/execute this assembly from within VS code, perhaps with a plugin.

Comment: In order to do that you need an assembler that understands this syntax (GAS), this has to be installed separately from VSCode (which is just an IDE)

Comment: NASM is available for mac [Install nasm on Mac OSX – Mac App Store](http://macappstore.org/nasm/) Though, personally, ssh'ed into a Linux box would be fine for all practical purposes. You can either open two-terminals (one to edit in and one to compile/link/run in) or you can use a single terminal and `tmux` or `screen` to handle multiple sessions though a single terminal.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use Intel syntax. To do that, add the directive `.intel_syntax noprefix` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: This assembly program won't work on a Mac; it uses a somewhat different 32-bit system call ABI than Linux.  Although `exit` might actually work, taking whatever random value was on the stack as the exit status arg, if it uses the same call number as Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a task to assemble and link your code, after that, you can use the [gdb extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DamianKoper.gdb-debug&ssr=false#qna) to debug your code.

To make this process faster, if you don't know how to do it, you can use the [.vscode folder](https://github.com/newtonsart/vscode-assembly).

As you are using AT&T syntax, you'll need to use the gas option to run the code.

If you still don't have gdb, you can install it opening a terminal and executing: `brew install gdb`.