# How to run Assembly Language on Visual Studio Code

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code

I **Lovesh Kumrawat** new User of Stack**overflow** and this is my 1st Question to you that, I am using a Visual Studio Code from January 2020, I used it for many languages like C/C++, Python, R, HTML so I conclude that the VS Code is a most useful and personally favourite IDE but at the end, a new requirement occurs that I want to learn 'Assembly Language' so, ** I am confused that did we able to run Assembly Language on Visual Studio Code & how** as we know **Visual Studio Code** supports many of the Language's then I bless it also supports **Assembly Language**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run asm in Visual Studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253227/run-asm-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253227/run-asm-in-visual-studio-code